# cross compilation of glib-2.33.1 for arc-linux-uclibc host on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: cross-compiling, glib, toolchain

I am cross-compiling glib-2.33.1 for arc-linux-uclibc host on ubuntu 14.04. But it fails with the error trace below while running `configure`

```
checking for guint32... yes
checking alignment of guint32... configure: error: in`/home/tars/glib-2.33.1':
configure: error: cannot compute alignment of guint32
```

how do I fix it and cross compile glib ?

Comment: What’s the output from `config.log`?

Comment: Hi Philip. Please find it here
https://gist.github.com/sampathkumar81293/18c943ac08e4820fe212c510f14148ff

Comment: conftest.c:199:12: error: storage size of 'test_array' isn't constant
 static int test_array [1 - 2 * !(((long int) offsetof (ac__type_alignof_, y)) >= 0)]; — Looks like your cross-compiler is not clever enough to work out array sizes using offsetof(). Can you get a more recent toolchain for this platform?

Comment: I will try this version https://github.com/foss-for-synopsys-dwc-arc-processors/toolchain/releases/tag/arc-2016.03 and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Update: was able to work it out for glib 2.40.2 for https://github.com/foss-for-synopsys-dwc-arc-processors/toolchain/releases/tag/arc-2016.03 version

Comment: Great! You should probably write an answer to your own question, or remove this from StackOverflow then.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this was because of the outdated cross compiler version. The toolchain `arc-2014.03` isn't working out array sizes of `guint` using `offsetof()`.

I was able to build glib 2.40.2 libraries for `arc-linux-uclibc` using  `arc-2016.03` toolchain on ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.